# Using .inc files when theming

Tags: drupal

I noticed in the Zen theme there were various PHP files with the .inc file extension .i.e. **template.conditional-styles.inc**. I've read/watched quite a few theming tutorials but none of them mentioned these files for theming, only the template.php.

Can anyone tell me when, if and how I should be using these files for theming.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for internal using in Zen theme, read comments please in files for what these.
For example, about **template.conditional-styles.inc**:

> // The code for conditional
>   stylesheets started out as a patch for
>   Zen. Now that
>  // it has been spun
>   out to its own separate module, It
>   would be nice to prevent
>  // code
>   drift between the Zen implementation
>   and the
>   conditional_styles.module,
>  // so
>   Zen now includes an exact copy of
>   conditonal_style module's:
>  //
>   conditional_styles.theme.inc,v 1.4
>   2008/09/14 23:26:47 johnalbin Exp

It will included in **template.theme-registry.inc** file, via this code:

```
function _zen_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  // Compute the conditional stylesheets.
  if (!module_exists('conditional_styles')) {
    include_once './' . drupal_get_path('theme', 'zen') . '/template.conditional-styles.inc';
    // _conditional_styles_theme() only needs to be run once.
    if ($theme == 'zen') {
      _conditional_styles_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path);
    }
  }
```

_zen_theme will included in **template.php**:

```
/**
 * Implements HOOK_theme().
 */
function zen_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  ...
  include_once './' . drupal_get_path('theme', 'zen') . '/template.theme-registry.inc';
```

Read about [hook_theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_theme/6).

Comment: Thanks Nikit. I had read the comments in the files but I was still a little unclear hense the question on here. I will read the hook_theme link you listed.

Many thanks